# Facebook Javascript SDK parent and popup page both redirecting in facebook login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-javascript-sdk

[image: Here is the print screen of my problem]

I'm having problem with my facebook Javascript SDK.... It's working but. when you click login... There will be popup show that sign you in  facebook (which is okay)..The problem is, when you signin the popup login the window do not close it stocks there... and the second problem is, the parent page is also redirect into facebook login page.. how can I fix that?
BTW, I'm using ruby on rails.

**Heres my facebook.js:**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", // App ID
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML

  });


    $(function() {
      $("#signin").click(function() {
        FB.login(function(response, event) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
             $.cookie("user_id", response.authResponse.userID);
             $.cookie("access_token", response.authResponse.accessToken);
             window.location = "#{auth_facebook_callback_url}";
          } else {
          }
        }, {scope: 'email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
      });
    });


    $(function() {
        $("#signout").click(function(){
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                if(response.authResponse){
                    FB.logout();
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
 };
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to provide 
`redirect_uri`
parameter as described here (where you also specify the scope):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/